# How to Pass PHP String Variable To JS From an Onclick Event

Tags: php, javascript, function, variables

This might have a simple answer, however I cannot figure out the correct syntax.  I have the following onclick event echoed on a php page:

```
$ratelink = text string...
echo '<div><span id="anything" onclick="updatePos('.$ratelink.')">Save</div>';
```

On my JS page, I have the function:

```
function updatePos(ratelink)
{
  alert(ratelink); 
}
```

My problem is that when $ratelink is a number, the variable will pass with no problems.  However, when $ratelink is a text string, like in the above example, nothing gets passed and the alert doesn't execute.

I think the following ('.$ratelink.') needs to be in a different syntax to pass text, but I don't know the exact format.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to enclose the string in quotes when passing to the JS function, as well as in PHP:

```
$ratelink = 'text string...';
echo '<div><span id="anything" onclick="updatePos(\''.$ratelink.'\')">Save</div>';
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
echo '<div><span id="anything" onclick=updatePos("'.$ratelink.'")>Save</div>';
```

if there is space in the `$ratelink` variable then it should be quoted in string....

Comment: Tried many ways but this one worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your string needs to be wrapped in quotes... so you'll need to make it

```
echo '<div><span id="anything" onclick="updatePos(\''.$ratelink.'\')">Save</div>';
```

and make sure that you escape the string as well if it might have any quotes in it

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the answers are correct. At least not the best option. Consider using `json_encode()` to pass any data from PHP to JS. This ensures that data is correctly escaped.

```
var myObj = <?=json_encode(array('php' => 'array'))?>;

console.log(myObj);
```