# Passing an argument to a Javascript function through PHP

Tags: javascript, php

i'm using PHP to get some values from the Database & echo html code. So i have something like this..

```
$values = $params->get('something');
```

And then i want to pass $values in to the doSomething() function of javascript.

```
echo('<html>');
echo('<head>');
echo('</head>');
echo('<body>');      
echo('<button type="button" onclick="doSomething()">');          
echo('</button>');      
echo('</br>');
echo('</body>');
echo('</html>');
```

Any suggestions? :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Pass PHP String Variable To JS From an Onclick Event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511709/how-to-pass-php-string-variable-to-js-from-an-onclick-event)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this -

```
echo('<button type="button" onclick="doSomething(\'' . $values . '\')">');
```

Comment: Browser throws: SyntaxError: illegal character

Comment: When does it show the SyntaxError? When loading the page? Or when clicking the button?

Comment: what is in `doSomething()`?

Comment: doSomething is a function on an other file..

and its like this..
function doSomething(value){
alert(value);
}

Comment: Then you have an error in your JS doSomething function I would guess - the function should look something like `function doSomething(values) {}`

Comment: Yes i'm pretty sure that my js func is correct typed... because if i remove the arguments it works fine.. the only problem is when adding the argument

Comment: What is the generated `HTML`?

Comment: it's huge.. i'm just working on a small module on the footer of the page.